# I need to change database from mysql to postgres for a JSP project which is using hibernate. How should I do it?

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, hibernate, jsp

I have to change DB from Mysql to Postgres. What changes should I make to my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/courier</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <mapping resource="com/pojo/Adminlogin.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/pojo/Contactus.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/pojo/Couriercompany.hbm.xml" />


        <mapping resource="com/pojo/Deliveryaddress.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/pojo/Domestic.hbm.xml" />

        <mapping resource="com/pojo/Pickupaddress.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/pojo/Pincode.hbm.xml" />

        <mapping resource="com/pojo/Userregistration.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/pojo/Placecourier.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Will I need to make further changes in my java files for the postgres queries to work. Do I need to add anything to my webcontent files which mainly have frontend JSP pages??

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL do *not* have the same SQL syntax.

Comment: No, but if you stick to standard JDBC you might be able to just switch drivers.  The moment you use vendor SQL you're lost.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly you have to change driver and dialect and of course the credentials and url.

If you did not use native queries everything should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hibernate.cfg.xml for posgresql and it will help you with basic hibernate configurations for posgresql.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb</property>



        <property name="connection_pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>



       <mapping class="org.javabrains.sanjaya.dto.UserDetails"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Would I need to edit anything from Java files ?

Comment: @asparkhour as another answer mentioned, if you're using native sql queries, you'll most probably have to edit them, if not, then you're probably good to go! Happy Coding